# Soundcard existing in alsamixer, but not in gnome

Tags: audio, alsa, gnome-3

I am having the following issue on a Fujitsu laptop with Debian Wheezy:

I have been fiddling around (a little too much) with my sound card, and have finally made it working again, **BUT** I can only access it using alsamixer (via terminal). That said, the sound card does not show up in the sound-settings in Gnome Classic (it also does not show any icon in the notification-area/bar (next to current battery level)).

So there's no sound-applet and the list from "System Settings"->"Sound"->"Sound cards" is empty, but there is sound!

So I cannot raise/decrease/mute/unmute the sound anywhere else but in alsamixer (not even via keyboard shortcuts).

Here's my `sudo aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269 Analog [ALC269 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here's `lspci | grep Audio`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Fujitsu Limited. Device 1475
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
        Memory at f2720000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

And `cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xf2720000 irq 44
```

Also testing `lsmod | grep snd`:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     30824  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   188858  1 
snd_hda_intel          26259  2 
snd_hda_codec          78031  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_hwdep              13186  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                68083  4 snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_page_alloc         13003  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq                45126  0 
snd_seq_device         13176  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              22917  3 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    52889  11 snd_timer,snd_seq_device,snd_seq,snd_pcm,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
soundcore              13065  1 snd
```

Anyone who has a hunch of why I cannot seem to get Gnome to find the soundcard?

Comment: I suggest you ask Super User. This site is a programming Q&A.

Comment: Why `sudo`? Don't you have access to the device nodes in `/dev/snd/`?

Comment: Sorry for the old reply, but I managed to resolve the issue by reinstalling the OS. Thanks for the support anyway.